# Android numbers of marker on Map

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps, markers

[Here is my Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Stv0.png)

[Here is my map markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96xFq.png)

In my  app i am  choosing a size and getting current location on click event , then inserting everything in SQLite Database. After that i am  making while loop and creating markers on my Map. Everything is working well but the displayed markers on map are lower than my rows in database. Its like i have 5 rows and only 2 markers are displayed when i max zoom on Map.
How i can display all , or they are just overlap each other?

```
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) 
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
   mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    Cursor res = activityA.myDB.getAllData();
    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
        //show message
        showMessage("Error", "No data found");
        return;
    }
    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        double ltd = Double.valueOf(res.getString(2));
        double lng = Double.valueOf(res.getString(3));
        LatLng hole = new LatLng(ltd, lng);
         Marker marker =  googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(hole)
                .title(res.getString(1)).visible(true));

    }
```

Comment: According to the data example you posted in the screen shot, your coordinates are overlapping so that only two markers would be visible.